# What does the phrase "today's dollars" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I do not completely understand the meaning of the phrase "today's dollars" in this sentence from a document on health care expenses:

> "... they will need almost $400,000 in today's dollars by the time they reach retirement age."

I suppose it is somehow related to price level growth and inflation, right? Could you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money

Comment: Unfortunately this question appears to be off-topic because it is about finance topics (time value of money) and not English.

Comment: Ok, well sorry for misinterpreting you.  I figured since you already had supposed that it was related to *price-level growth and inflation* and wanted a more detailed explanation, that the explanation you were looking for was "What is the time value of money"  Also, the answer you accepted, explains that concept

Comment: This question should be redirected to the Economics forum, if it exists. In fact, this not an English question at all. In Russian or Indian, or Chinese, one would certainly also say "In today's kopeks/rupees/yuans, that would cost us 300 burgers."

Comment: The exact same expression exists in Russian, too (and in other languages). *In today's dollars* = *в сегодняшних долларах*. Identical, word-for-word. The meaning is very transparent, too, so why not go with Occam's razor and see if it leads anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Money loses value over time.

While $5 might buy a burger today, in 20 years time, it might only buy one tenth of a burger.
Or in other words, $5 buys one burger today, but you need $50 to buy one burger in 20 years.

In this context '$5 in today's money' means 'Enough money to buy one burger'.

For the context of your question, $400,000 buys x amount of power, food, nursing home care etc today, you'll need the equivalent amount of money (ie more than $400,000) at retirement age.

In terms of relating this to inflation, if you put $400,000 in a bank account today, and it accumulated interest at the exact same rate of inflation, while your bank account in the future would show more than $400,000, it would have $400,000 of 'today's money', or '2013 money'.

Comment: In the *dirty thirties* money **gained** value over time. That is the motivation behind stories of those who stuffed their mattress full of dollar bills. It's called deflation, and it can be very painful for anyone with debt. It is erroneous to assume that inflation is  given, as the reason for Quantitative Easing after the 2008 crash were fears (rightly of wrongly) of large-scale deflation taking hold of the economy.

Answer (score 3):

It's referring to inflation. When these elderly folk being referred to were younger and began their retirement savings, everything was much less expensive so saving up $50 000.00 would be a large amount of money to retire with. But nowadays $50 000.00 isn't much money in today's dollars.